# How to pass a variable from HTML to the backend in Flask

Tags: flask, url, request, selecteditem

There are so many *[td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)* elements with a tag and I want to know that user clicked which element and I want to pass from HTML to the backend and process with the user's selection on the backend.

This is my HTML content:

```html
<a href="/selected" ????><td>{{ options1 }}</td></a>
<a href="/selected"><td>{{ options2 }}</td></a>
<a href="/selected"><td>{{ options3 }}</td></a>
<a href="/selected"><td>{{ options4 }}</td></a>
<a href="/selected"><td>{{ options5 }}</td></a>
<a href="/selected"><td>{{ options6 }}</td></a>
```

When a user clicked one, I want to send it to the backend:

```
@app.route('/selected', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def selected():
selected_option = request.args.get('????')
return render_template("selected.html", selected_option=selected_option)
```

How can I fill the question marks?

Comment: The code, as posted, does not appear to be valid Python code (indentation). Did you copy it from a web page somewhere?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*).

Answer (score 1):

Having the separate variables for `options1`, `options2`, etc probably makes this a hassle for a few reasons:

- You'll need to manually update the hard-coding of the template to add more options.
- The URL part of each option, might be different from the link text.

You may wish to define your options in a dictionary:

```
sections = {'first-option': 'I am the first option',
            'second-option': 'Click me for fun and profit',
            'third-option': 'All flights have been cancelled',
           }
```

Now on the page which generates your link bar, if you pass that across:

```
return render_template('some_page.html', SECTIONS=sections)
```

You can then do something like:

```
{% for key, value in SECTIONS.items() %}
  <a href="{{url_for('selected', section=key)}}">{{value}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This will automatically generate the correct URLs, which are compatible with the following view function:

```
@app.route('/selected/<section>')
def selected(section):
    # Assuming the first URL:
    print (section) # 'first-option'
    print (sections[section]) # 'I am the first option'

    return render_template("selected.html", selected_option=section)
```

You may also wish to have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/0e242c63afb9539e98869ad0f77974ab) which takes the concept a bit further.

This also uses a context processor to insert that `SECTIONS` variable into all pages, rather than passing it to the individual `render_template` functions.